# Accepting cookie pop-up with Selenium in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, popupwindow

I need to scrape a website, but first I need to remove the pop-up window for cookies. Following other questions, I have written the following code (with the appropriate link for url):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

PATH="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.maximize_window()
url='https://dait.interno.gov.it/elezioni/open-data'
driver.get(url)
sel='#popup-buttons > button.agree-button.eu-cookie-compliance-default-button'
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,sel))).click()
```

What confuses me is that it seemed to have worked once, and only once even if I didn't change anything in the code. Now it doesn't do anything anymore and I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point
```

I have obtained the CSS locator by "copying selector" when inspecting the page.

Comment: Can you try verifying the locator is still relevant for the dom? also if you could add the html for the page, i will be able to figure it out better.

Comment: I don`t believe it happens "only once".  Selenium is designed to create totally new profile by default. Thus  popup should appear every time you run script

Comment: @Rohit I added the link to the page in the body of the question. It's a link to an open-data page from the Italian government.

Comment: @YevhenB The pop-up appears every time, but the code doesn't close the pop-up window, but I'm pretty sure it did work at least once. I don't recall having edited the code since then, but it doesn't do it anymore